# Express direct to the wrong endpoint in production but work perfectly on development

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

express direct to the wrong endpoint on the production environment but works fine on development.
I had built my application using express for back-end and react for front-end and passport for authentication, Here now I'm facing issue with endpoint `/auth/google`. when I click the button, it should direct to express endpoint `auth`, but express directs to react app not found component.

simply my app does not hit endpoint `auth/google` rather render react page

[image]

*here the codes*

**server.js**

```js
app.use('/auth', require('./router/auth')) // should direct here
app.use('/media', require('./router/media')) 
app.use('/admin', require('./router/admin')) 
app.use('/user', require('./router/user'))

const httpServer = http.createServer(app)

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
 app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, '../' + 'build', 'favicon.ico')))

 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../' + 'build')));

 app.get("*", (req, res) => { // but always goes here
 res.sendFile(path.join(path.join(__dirname, '../' + 'build', 'index.html')));
  });
}

const PORT = 8080

httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
 console.log('Server up at:' + PORT)
})
```

**/router/auth.js**

```js
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', { // and should hit this 
  scope: ['profile', 'email']
}))
router.get(
  '/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google'),
  (req, res) => {
    req.app.set('user', res.req.user)
    return res.redirect('/auth/sign')
  }
)

module.exports = router
```

**passport.js**

```js
export default function (passport) {
  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user)
  })

  passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user)
  })

  // GOOGLE OAuth
  passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback'
      },
      function (_, __, profile, done) {
        profile = {
          ...profile,
          email: profile.emails && profile.emails[0].value,
          profileUrl: profile.photos && profile.photos[0].value
        }
        authUser(profile, done) // function for save user
      }
    )
  )
}
```

**react app.js**

```js
 <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Main} />
          <Route path="/home" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/ad/:id" exact component={Ad} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/postad" exact component={createAd} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/ad/edit/:id" exact component={UpdateAd} />
          <Route path="/user/:id" exact component={User} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/setting" exact component={Setting} />
          <PublicRoute path="/sign" exact component={ProviderSign} />
          <Route path="*" exact={true} component={PageNotFound} /> // but render this
 </Switch>
```

**TLDR**

My was was also redirecting to react page when it was set `"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"`, and After I found this `http-proxy-middleware` and setup proxy on the client src folder

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = app => {
  app.use(proxy("/auth/google", { target: "http://localhost:8080/" }));
  app.use(proxy("/auth/facebook", { target: "http://localhost:8080/" }));
};
```

after this works fine when I start my node server on port `8080` and client on port `3000`,

And this is my login page button to hit endpoint `/auth/google`

```html
<Button className={classes.authBtn}> 
 <a className={classes.removeStyle} href="/auth/google">Google</a>     
</Button>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying when you navigate to `/auth/google` you can see that it does hit the server but skips those routes and ends up in the catch all route on the server? Are you sure it's not always being by the client catch-all after the initial render?

Comment: So this is happening only for the route `/auth/google` and not for any other route?

Comment: yeah, @James. this is only happening for `/auth/google`

Comment: I think @James is correct here. (I'm not a front end dev, so stand to be corrected). Try changing the catch-all handler to something else, e.g. `notfound` and then hit your button. If you get a client side error, you know you are not hitting the API. It doesn't look like you are sending a request to your API server.

Comment: Did you use create-react-app to generate the project? If so, what version? Did you at any point enable the service worker?

Comment: yeah, I used `create-react-app` to generate my project and I had enabled service worker for PWA purpose. @JonChurch

Comment: Maybe try `unregister` the service worker and see if that helps. According to [this comment](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5520#issuecomment-364598336) folks have had issues similar to yours in production caused by service workers. Ultimately, the <a> link you're using should go directly to the express application, but in your example it appears that React Router is catching it instead (imo). If you can add a log line to the Express catchall and prove that Express is handling it, then I'd say that putting your API routes at a different endpoint is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

A solution for me is to, create a `routes.js` file like:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();

const authRouter = require('./router/auth');
const mediaRouter = require('./router/media');
const adminRouter = require('./router/admin');
const userRouter = require('./router/user');

router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(200).json({
    isSuccess: true,
    message: "Server is up and running!"
  });
});

app.use('/auth', authRouter); 
app.use('/media', mediaRouter); 
app.use('/admin', adminRouter); 
app.use('/user', userRouter);

router.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    isSuccess: false,
    message: "Invalid address!"
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Modify your `server.js` file as:

```
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
const indexRouter = require("./routes"); // your routes.js

app.use("/api", indexRouter);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
 app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, '../' + 'build', 'favicon.ico')))

 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../' + 'build')));

 app.get("*", (req, res) => { // but always goes here
 res.sendFile(path.join(path.join(__dirname, '../' + 'build', 'index.html')));
  });
}

const PORT = 8080;

httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
 console.log('Server up at:' + PORT)
})
```

And finally modify your `auth.js` as:

```
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google', { // and should hit this 
  scope: ['profile', 'email']
}))
router.get(
  '/google/callback',
  passport.authenticate('google'),
  (req, res) => {
    req.app.set('user', res.req.user)
    return res.redirect('api/auth/sign') // Changed this endpoint
  }
)

module.exports = router
```

This approach separates your API and Front-end routes. Hope this works for you.

Comment: We already solved this by moving to `react-google-login` from `passportjs`  due to deadline. after going through your code looks like this approuse might work. But what ever thanks for your answer, I will give the award to this answer.